# Set number of cores in OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, openmp, intel, cpu-cores

I'm running my program on an Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-1650 v3 
http://ark.intel.com/products/82765/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-1650-v3-15M-Cache-3_50-GHz

The processor has 6 CPUs(6 cores), I'm trying to set the number of CPUs my prorgram is using. My application is using openmp.
I'm not trying to set the number of threads, but the number of CPUs. How can I do that?

Comment: OMP_NUM_THREADS env var or omp_set_num_threads(int) runtime call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use environment variables controlling thread affinity?

If you're compiling your code with gcc, you may want to use [`GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html#GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY) or [`OMP_PLACES`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/OMP_005fPLACES.html#OMP_005fPLACES).

For Intel compilers, there are `KMP_AFFINITY` and `KMP_PLACE_THREADS`, see the [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-thread-affinity-control).

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, although it is a good answer to a different question.

Comment: The question is about setting the number of cores, not of threads. There are cases where OMP_NUM_THREADS has been set but all threads are executed on one core, while others are idle. In that situation, setting thread affinity might help.

Comment: Yes but affinity does not control any count - thread, core or otherwise.